# Please remove the Circles/Outlines around the Voting Buttons

Tags: discussion, design

While the new Upvote/Downvote button design is a nice attempt at a new style, it's too big, detracts from the actual answer post, doesn't fit in with the rest of the post design, and makes an otherwise great and long-lasting layout design feel cluttered.

[image: Old vs New Voting Buttons]

---

Compare the whole layout of an answer post with the "new" buttons VS the old buttons:

> **NEW**
>
> > [image: Why new voting buttons are a step down]
>
> ---
>
> ### ------ VS ------
>
> ---
>
> **OLD**
>
> > [image: Old voting buttons blend in more naturally]

[Slider Comparison](https://imgsli.com/MTEzOTA0)

---

Looking at this, the old buttons also look a tad too big. Here are some alternate suggestions I quickly whipped up:

[image: Alternative design suggestions]

The only positive outcome of this redesign is that there's now a clear separation between the "sidebar" (with the voting buttons) and the main post area -- the two "columns" appear more nicely. With the old buttons, the distinction is a bit blurry and everything seems a bit "floaty".

But I mean, who asked for this?

Comment: You're looking for the A/B test discussion on Meta SO, which is the only site where this is currently running: [Updated button styling for vote arrows: currently in A/B testing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418851/updated-button-styling-for-vote-arrows-currently-in-a-b-testing)

Comment: @animuson: Thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction. Didn't realize that and was wondering why no one else was speaking of this. Found the relevant thread now 